# CORS and Authentication deadlock with AWS Serverless Application Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth, cors, aws-serverless

I have a front-end written in Blazor WASM. It authenticates users through OAuth0 and makes requests to an API using the access_token.

My API is an AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) Api with Lambda Proxy integrations configured thus:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 120
    MemorySize: 512
    Environment:
      Variables:
        VICTUALS_TABLE: !Sub "Victuals-${stage}"
        AUTH_DOMAIN: "gantonopoulos.eu.auth0.com"
#  Api:
#    Cors:
#      AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,DELETE,GET,HEAD,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
#      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Amz-Date, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token'"
#      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
#      AllowCredentials: false      
    
Resources:
  PantrymonyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: LambdaTokenAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          LambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthenticateUser.Arn
  
  AuthenticateUser:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: Pantrymony.back::Pantrymony.back.Lambda.Authentication::AuthenticateAsync
      Runtime: dotnet6
      Description: Lambda handler for authentication
      
  GetUnits:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: Pantrymony.back::Pantrymony.back.Lambda.ApiFunctions::GetUnits
      Runtime: dotnet6
      Description: A Lambda to return the supported units
      Events:
        GetVictualsApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref PantrymonyApi
            Path: /units
            Method: get

  Options:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: Pantrymony.back::Pantrymony.back.Lambda.ApiFunctions::Options
      Runtime: dotnet6
      Description: A Lambda to return CORS requests
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 60
      Events:
        GetVictualsApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
            RestApiId: !Ref PantrymonyApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: options
```

(I have more end points with GET-POST-PUT-DELETE verbs)

I have a Lambda for authorization, verifying the received access_token against a registered OAuth0 API instance (Audience) as done [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/).

To enable CORS, I have tried two scenarios. a) I have enabled it globally, by removing the comments in the *Globals:Api* section and commenting the Options lambda.
b) By using an OPTIONS Lambda for all endpoints I do not define, and removing authorization from it (an idea I got [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html)) and commenting out the CORS header in the *Globals:Api* (as the file is now).

In both cases, I programmed my Lambdas to also reply with the CORS headers seen in the *Globals:Api:Cors* section (as I think is suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)).

In both cases I get the same behaviour:

When I call my lambdas, either directly through the AWS console, or through the API-Gateway in the AWS console, all of them succeed and return the CORS headers.

Then I try to call my GET endpoints through Postman, appending the access_token. I observe the following:

The first (and all subsequent done to the same endpoint) call will succeed and return the data, but any other call to a different endpoint fails with code 403 and message:

```
{
    "Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource"
}
```

Sometimes the request to the second endpoint also succeeds but then the one to a third endpoint no.
All three requests use the same token.

When I try to access the OPTION Lambda through postman (in scenario b)), without passing the token, I get an 403,

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

which I do not understand since I have deactivated authentication for that verb.
If I pass the token, I get a

```
{TOKEN} not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer {TOKEN}'
```

Finally, when I try to access the API through my frontend, sometimes my forntend succeeds in the first GET request (as postman does) but when the second comes I get:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://gu1szp41pe.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/units' from origin 'https://localhost:7260' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
https:/…0.2.au5m8gyp9k.js:1GET https://gu1szp41pe.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/units net::ERR_FAILED
```

I think I have tried all I could find in the documentation and I have run out of ideas.
What could I be missing.
I thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your authorizer's `Token Source` to the `AllowHeaders`

Click on Enable CORS, then add the Token Source to the end of Access-Control-Allow-Headers

```
AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Amz-Date, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token, {your Token Source}'"
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What do you mean by "Token Source". My frontend or my OAuth0 application? And what value exactly? Could you please point me to an example?